# Azure http function times out when triggered by other function but works when triggered directly

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure http function that almost always times out when called by another Azure function but always works when called directly. More info:

I have two Azure functions in Python:

- a time triggered (scheduled) function
- an http triggered function

The time triggered function fetches a list of items and then calls the http triggered function for each of the items, where the item is passed as a string argument. It uses python *requests* and the function URL of the http triggered function. The http triggered function then runs some calculations that take 1-2 seconds.

If the time triggered function runs, it tries to call the http triggered function but 95% of the time, the http function times out with a `504.0 GatewayTimeout` after 5minutes and doesn't return anything, causing the time triggered function to time out as well (since more than 5 minutes passed). Weirdly enough, sometimes it seems to work even though the parameters didn't change.

If I call the http function directly through the Azure portal or via python/curl using the *exact same* parameters (i.e. the exact same string argument) and the *exact same* function URL it always works and returns values after 1-2 seconds, leading me to think that there is no error in my code that prevents function execution but rather something else.

Any ideas what might be causing this problem and what steps I could take to try to fix it?

Edit:

Time triggered function (shortened):

```
import datetime
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import requests
import os
import time


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = (
        datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    )

    items_without_data = ["item1", "item2"]

    cloud_function_url = os.environ.get("MY_CF_URL")
    for i, item in enumerate(items_without_data):
        
        r = requests.post(
            cloud_function_url,
            json={"item_id": item},
            timeout=300,
        )  
        if r.status_code != 200:
            logging.error(
                f"cloud function call failed. {r.text}, for item {item}"
            )
        # make sure we don't hit the rate limit of 40 calls per minute
        if i % 19 == 0:
            time.sleep(60)
```

HTTP triggered function:

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import json
import SomeOtherFunctionThatCallsAnExternalAPI


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info("CF processed a request.")

    item_id = req.params.get("item_id")

    if not item_id:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            item_id = req_body.get("item_id")

    logging.info(f"Request for item {item_id}")

    if not item_id:
        logging.error("Error: item_id missing")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "required parameter item_id is missing", status_code=400
        )
    
    logging.info(f"Getting XXX for item {item_id}")

    IDD = SomeOtherFunctionThatCallsAnExternalAPI()
    response_data, error = IDD.get_xxx(
        item_id=item_id, write_to_db=True
    )

    if not response_data:
        logging.error(f"Error: {error}")
        return func.HttpResponse(error, status_code=500)

    logging.info(f"Processed request for item {item_id}")
    return func.HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(response_data), mimetype="application/json", status_code=200
    )
```

Comment: shared it (shortened version)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a timer trigger **"TimerTrigger"** and using default HTTP trigger code and I am a triggering HTTP trigger using timer trigger.

**`TimerTrigger`**:

```py
   import datetime
   import requests
   import logging
   import os
   import azure.functions as func
   
   def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest):
       utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
           tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
   
       http_endpoint = os.environ.get("url")
       parameter_name = 'name'
   
       try:
           name_value = 'John'
           response = requests.post(f'{http_endpoint}?{parameter_name}={name_value}')
   
           if response.status_code == 200:
               logging.info('HTTP request successful')
           else:
               logging.error(f'HTTP request failed with status code {response.status_code}')
       except Exception as e:
           logging.error(f'Error making HTTP request: {str(e)}')
   
       logging.info(f'Python timer trigger function ran at {utc_timestamp}')
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

This is my code to trigger the HTTP trigger url where I am passing the name parameter for the HTTP trigger.

```py
response = requests.post(f'{http_endpoint}?{parameter_name}={name_value}')
```